# Better ways to get a string from user

Tags: c, pointers, char, scanf, fgets

I want to get a string from the user( actually I want to control the length, but have no way), and output it. I try a way which is work (but I don't think it is good solution because it is easily overflowed or takes too much memory. Any one can provide a better way to do that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char p[1024];   //there if i use 'char *p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024)' error too.
  int i=0;
  fgets(p,1024,stdin); //there if i use 'scanf("%s",p)', wrong.
  while(p[i]!='\0'&&i<1024){
    printf("%c",p[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

can anyone provide a better way to make it and explain my error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code. And what's wrong with `fgets`? What does not work? How is the output you get different from the output you expect? You can [edit] your question. Please read also this: [ask]

Comment: Works fine for me. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Function `fgets()` can't overflow the buffer if you passed its correct length, but it can truncate the input. If the input string contains a newline `\n` then it was not truncated. Otherwise if the string length + terminator is less than the buffer size, it was not truncated, but there was no newline (for example the last line in a file). Otherwise there is more to read. If you allocate the buffer dynamically, it can be extended in that case, and `fgets()` repeated at the position of the previous string terminator. That can be done in a loop until the input is complete.

Comment: ... note that you don't need to check `i<1024` because `fgets()` is guaranteed to provide the string terminator, which you check for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you want to read in a string without having to hardcode a size. That's not possible with `fgets`. You give it a hardcoded size, hope that the input fits, and if the input doesn't fit, it gets truncated.

Instead, you can use the new(er) [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), if your compiler is POSIX-compatible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    getline(&p, &size, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; p[i] != '\0' &&i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    free(p);
    printf("size %zu",size);
    return 0;
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the size of the buffer. `getline` takes care of that. You just have to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Note that `getline()` is a gcc extension and not part of standard C.

Comment: Thank you so much, but 'getline' is not a general solution, it can't work in my compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane `getline()` is not a gcc extension.  [`getline()` is standard POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you, but `getline()` is not mentioned in the C18 standard, and POSIX gets a mention in its Bibliography section.

Comment: @WeatherVane You specifically stated "`getline()` is a gcc extension".  That's not correct and that's what I addressed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle are you saying that gcc does not support `getline()`? Or that gcc supports POSIX which in turn provides `getline()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane According to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), it was originally a GNU extension, and was then standardized in POSIX.1-2008.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to control the length, but have no way

True that code can not reach out to the user with a magic arm and restrain one from typing, but code can (and should IMO), limit the input *saved* to some generous amount, say [1024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.) to read a *name*.

Input beyond sanity is better thought of as an attack than a valid extreme.  Such input does not need to be saved in its entirety, just detected and handled.

Use `fgets()`

```
int main(void) {
  char p[1024];
  if (fgets(p, sizeof p,stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("Input closed");
    return -1;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(p);
  if (len > 0 && p[len - 1] == '\n') {  // lop off potential \n
    p[--len] = '\0';
  }
  if (len + 1 == sizeof p) {  // too long a line
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      ; // consume rest of line
    }
    printf("Input too long, first part <%s>\n", p);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Input OK <%s>\n", p);
  return 0;
}
```